# How do i verify that port 5555 is open?

Tags: windows, networking, command-prompt

I have a task in a lab for my cyber-security class where I have to verify that the port 5555 is open and not in use via Command Prompt. I have tried the following command with these flags: 
[command used to check port 5555](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcfN8.png)

Comment: Please add the command text instead of adding a screenshot.

Comment: This is the command text netstat -na | find "5555"

Comment: When i tried that command, there was no output, just blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `netstat` or `sudo lsof -i tcp:5555`.

If you don't get a response on your terminal, it means that there's nothing running on port 5555.

Answer (score 2):

- You can do a nmap scan on that port to see if its open or close; also you can get more information about the port if its open this way.

```
nmap -vvv <ip> -p 5555
```

- if you are looking for a fast way you can try to connect to that port and see using netcat or telnet

```
nc localhost 5555
telnet localhost 5555
```

if the port is close your connection will drop if its open the connection wont close if the application running on port 5555 has a header you can also see that.

---

in case you looking for open ports in your own computer you can do `ss -lnpt` which will show all open ports. then you can grep for port 5555